# Multiplicities of ordered pairs in pairing of two multisets

Tags: combinatorics

I have two multisets, $X$ and $Y$. Each is a $k$-combination with repetition of a set $N=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$, where $n$ can be greater, equal, or smaller than $k$.

Example 1: $k=7$, $n=3$

$X=\{1,1,1,2,2,3,3\}$

$Y=\{1,2,2,2,3,3,3\}$

I record the multiplicities of each element in $X$ and $Y$ in $n$-dimensional "multiplicity vectors" $\mathbf m_X$ and $\mathbf m_Y$.

Example 1 (continued):

$\mathbf m_X = (3,2,2)$

$\mathbf m_Y = (1,3,3)$

I construct a multiset $S_{XY}$ of ordered pairs $(x,y)$, where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. (The set $S_{XY}$ is a subset of the cartesian product of $X$ and $Y$.) There are $k!$ different ways of pairing elements of $X$ and $Y$ up to construct $S_{XY}$. Some the resulting $k!$ sets $S_{XY}$ can be identical due to repetitions of elements in $X$ and $Y$, but for the sum at the end of this question, I consider them to be different multisets.

Example 1A:

$S_{XY}=\{(1,1),(1,2),(1,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,3),(3,3)\}$

Example 1B:

$S_{XY}=\{(1,3),(1,3),(1,3),(2,2),(2,2),(3,1),(3,2)\}$

I record the multiplicities of each ordered pair in $S_{XY}$ in an $n\times n$-dimensional "multiplicity matrix" $\mathbf M$. Every row of $\mathbf M$ is an ordered non-negative integer partition of one element of $\mathbf m_X$. Every column in an ordered non-negative integer partitions of an element of $\mathbf m_y$.

Example 1A (continued):

$\mathbf M = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$

Example 1B (continued):

$\mathbf M = \begin{pmatrix}0&0&3\\0&2&0\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Using only the multiplicity vectors $\mathbf m_X$ and $\mathbf m_Y$, I want to express the sum of multinomials

\begin{equation}
\sum_{S_{XY}}\frac{k!}{\prod_{i,j,=1}^n(m_{ij}!)}\,,\end{equation}

where $ m_{ij}$ is an element of $\mathbf M$ and the $\sum_{S_{XY}}$ denotes summing over all $k!$ multisets $S_{XY}$.

Comment: When you say "There are $k!$ different ways of pairing elements of $X$ and $Y$ up to construct $S_{XY}$", I don't quite follow you. Do you mean that $S_ {XY}$ is obtained by fixing some ordering of elements in $X$ and in $Y$, choosing some permutation $\sigma\in S_k$, and then setting $S_{XY}=\{(x_i,y_{\sigma(i)})\,|\,i=1,2,\dots,k\}$? So that, after the initial ordering of $X$ and $Y$ are fixed, the $S_{XY}$ are in correspondence with the $\sigma$?

Comment: I constuct $S_{XY}$ as if elements of $X$ and $Y$ were labelled (meaning: all elements in $X$ are different, there are no duplicates, all multiplicities are 1). In that case there would be different $k!$ pairings.